# How to connect existing account to Stripe Connect?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

It seems very complicated to me how to connect an existing Stripe account as Connected account to Stripe Connect.

I successfully created a new connected account both through the dashboard and through the PHP API.

But I want my clients to see their transactions in their own account dashboard. Is that possible?

I've read about using an oAuth URL, and when I use it on another account, it sees that I am logged in and connects, but it creates a new Standard account with a new `acct_` account ID and no account information.

This new account is not visible in the logged in account's dashboard, but is only seen in Connected accounts of the account using Stripe Connect.

This seems to me like a basic question, but I have been searching for hours.

Is someone able to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your clients are signing up for Stripe themselves directly and later connecting to your platform, you should use [OAuth to have them connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-standard-accounts) to your platform. This shouldn't create a brand-new Stripe account for them but should use their existing account.

Comment: Thank you! Does this work when both accounts are in test mode as well?

Comment: Because the `stripe_user_id` (`acct_`) that is returned is different from the account ID (`acct_`) shown in the dashboard of the user

Comment: It should work with test mode, yes. After clicking on the OAuth link, users should log into their existing Stripe account. If they have access to multiple accounts, they will be prompted to choose whether they want to connect one of those accounts to your platform or create a brand-new Stripe account.